# Car Horn does not work during the morning hours

Tags: toyota, horn

My car horn does not work during morning hours. It starts to work when the environment gets heated up. Same issue with the "TRIP" key of the Multi function. Car Model - Toyota Aqua - 2013

Comment: It hasn't had it coffee yet! Seriously, its a defective horn button assembly.